# Meteor local client collection with React components

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I am using Meteor with React as the view layer. Does anyone have or know of an example using this combination to query a local client collection and pass that data as props among React components?

I am talking about something like a client component that has:

```
const flashMessages = new Mongo.Collection(null)
```

...in it and some methods like add, remove etc on it. Then how best to display that data in the current or another React component. I found several examples doing something like this with Blaze, but none with React. I am not sure if/how the data would be reactive in this scenario and if something like `getMeteorData()` would need to be in the mix or not.

Any advise or examples on how best to handle to this combination would be great!

Comment: I believe the "official" tutorial is pretty straightforward about this: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app

Comment: That does not go into detail on using a React view layer with a LOCAL ONLY collection (which BTW is what I asked). But I figured it out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that may be interested in this, here is what I got to work. I have a messages module, but you can apply this principle to any other type of collection you want or need:

```
const Messages = {
  // Local (client-only) collection
  collection: new Mongo.Collection(null),

  addMessage(message, level) {
    // set default type to error
    level = (typeof level === 'undefined') ? 'error': level;
    // Store in the local collection
    this.collection.insert({message: message, level: level, isDialog: false});
  },

  addDialogMessage(message, level) {
    // set default type to error
    level = (typeof level === 'undefined') ? 'error': level;
    // Store in the local collection
    this.collection.insert({message: message, level: level, isDialog: true});
  },

  removeMessage(messageId) {
    this.collection.remove(messageId);
  },

  clearMessages() {
    let messages = this.collection.find({}).fetch()
    messages.map((message) =>
      this.collection.remove(message._id)
    )
  }
};

export default Messages
```

This houses you "database" methods. Then in my case I have a component that displays `an instance` of this data:

```
import { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import ReactMixin  from 'react-mixin'
import Messages from 'common/client/components/flash/MessageTest'


@ReactMixin.decorate(ReactMeteorData)
export default class EpFlash extends Component {

  getMeteorData() {
    let messages
    if (this.props.isDialog) {
     messages = Messages.collection.find({isDialog: true}).fetch()
    }else{
     messages = Messages.collection.find({isDialog: false}).fetch()
    }
    return {
      messages
    }
  }

  remove = (id) => {
    Messages.removeMessage(id)
  }

  render() {
    let styles = {
      error: {color: '#fff', background: '#a94442',
        textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: '5px'},
      warning: {color: '#fff', background: '#f0ad4e',
        textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: '5px'},
      info: {color: '#fff', background: '#337ab7',
        textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: '5px'},
      success: {color: '#fff', background: '#5cb85c',
        textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: '5px'}
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {this.data.messages.map((message, index) =>
          <div key={index}>
            <span  className="cute-row"
              style={styles.error}>
              {message.message}
            <span onClick={this.remove.bind(this, message._id)}
              style={{float: 'right', cursor: 'pointer', paddingRight: '5px'}}>
              <i>&times;</i>
            </span>
            </span>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here you can apply animations, timeouts, or whatever and because of React each place you use this is it's own component instance. I am going to make the classes in the example dynamic but haven't implemeted that yet. I left them in to give you an idea of what is possible.

Then wherever you use this, you combine it with the methods from your database module to get whatever you need. I you run this in 2 different tabs or windows, you'll see each is it's own instance. You could get pretty fancy with this, but remember that the collection is wiped on page refresh or browser shutdown, so if you need to pre-populate anything for an instance, you need to do it in something like `componentWillMount()`. I would also clear each instance in `ComponentWillUnmount()` or someplace just to be safe.

```
import { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import Messages from 'common/client/components/flash/MessageTest'
import EpFlash from 'common/client/components/flash/EpFlash'

export default class Wrapper extends Component {

  add = () => {
    Messages.addMessage('crap', 'error')
  }

  addDialog = () => {
    Messages.addDialogMessage('dialog crap', 'error')
  }

  clear = () => {
    Messages.clearMessages()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Messages</h3>
        <EpFlash isDialog={true}/>
        <button onClick={this.add}>Add</button>
        <button onClick={this.addDialog}>Add Dialog</button>
        <button onClick={this.clear}>Clear</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This is just an simple prototype with room for improvement, but it works and hopefully gives anyone else interested in something like this a starting point.

P.S. getMeteorData is changing to createContainer in Meteor 1.3. This example is based on 1.2 since 1.3 is brand new.